# Rails/Ruby/Postgres - LoadError cannot load such file -- pg_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

I am trying to call a Ruby script (which connects to a postgres db) using the rails controller below, however it appears it is having problems loading one of the PG gem files. I have set my require statement to require 'pg' and tried the absolute path as well (require `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@railsTest/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg/`). The file 'pg_ext' is in fact present in the directory. Additionally, I can run the ruby script standalone without any problems (dbrubyscript.rb), however when rails is added to this equation it craps out with a `cannot load such file -- pg_ext` error.

Any direction here would be much appreciated as I have not been able to find anything online that fixes this issue

**Rails controller:**

```
class TestdlController < ApplicationController
def runmyscript
  load "/usr/local/rvm/my_app/ruby_scripts/reports/dbrubyscript.rb"
  send_file '/usr/local/rvm/tmp/failedtests.csv', :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => 'inline'
  flash[:notice] = "Reports are being processed..."
end
end
```

**.rb file (dbrubyscript.rb)  has the following:**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'

connects to (production) database
@conn = PGconn.connect("zzzzz.test.prod", 5432,"","","yyyyy_prod" ,"postgres", "xxxxxx")
.....
```

**Trace Error:**
 LoadError in TestdlController#runmyscript

> cannot load such file -- pg_ext
>
> Rails.root: /usr/local/rvm/my_app Application Trace | Framework Trace
>   | Full Trace app/controllers/Testdl_controller.rb:3:in `runmyscript'
>
> This error occurred while loading the following files:
>   /usr/local/rvm/my_app/ruby_scripts/reports/dbrubyscript.rb
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@railsTest/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg/
>   pg_ext

Comment: have you gem installed the 'pg' gem with dependencies?

Comment: I'm not sure if I installed the gem with dependencies. When I initially installed the gem I used the following command:  gem install pg -- --with-pg-config='/usr/local/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config'

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add `gem 'pg'` to the Gemfile in Rails and install all gems with dependencies by running `bundle install`?

Comment: see this tread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147877/ruby-pgsql-error-on-rails-start-cannot-load-such-file-pg-ext-loaderror

Answer (score 1):

Try running ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@railsTest/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg/ext/extconf.rb and see what errors you get.  That helped me determine that in my case, my PostgreSQL client was too old.  Your error may be different since you appear to have a current-ish versioninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I have a stand alone ruby script. It connects via `pg` to `postgres` and worked if I ran it directly from the `shell`.

If I tried to run it via rspec I get the Error `cannot load such file -- pg`.

**Solved**: The problem for rspec was, the `pg` gem was not defined in the `Gemfile`. After put pg into `Gemfile`, and retestet via rspec, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a line to your Gemfile:

```
gem "pg"
```

Then run bundler via the command line:

```
bundle install
```

Rails uses Bundler to manage your gems and dependencies. You can read a bit more about the idea behind Bundler here: http://gembundler.com/v1.2/rationale.html