# Redmine/Ruby/Rails/Postgresql - cannot load such file -- pg_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine-2.3.0 on fedora-18(64-bit). I followed instructions at redmine's official user's guide(http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall).
Everything went well until i run: rake generate_secret_token. I got the following error:

> rake aborted! cannot load such file -- pg_ext

I have postgresql-9.2.4-1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716532/rails-ruby-postgres-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-pg-ext

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did try suggestions from other questions, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem:

Had my *pg_ext.so* file under:
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/

Copied it to:
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/

Comment: I had the same problem and this tip helps. But I don't think that this is a real solution.

Comment: I got this error only with ruby 2.0.0p247, if I downgrade to p0 there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I only started seeing this on 2.0.0-p247.  Check out this output:

```
>find ~/.rvm/gems -name "pg_ext*"
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1/ext/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/jshort/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/Users/jshort/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin11.4.2/pg_ext.bundle
```

I just copied the pg_ext.bundle to the 2.0.0-p247's lib directory like the 1.9.3 versions.

Also note that odd directory at the end like the gem installer put that in the wrong location.

Comment: thanks, that seems to have fixed it for me, now I'm getting a different error

Answer (score -1):

also fedora x64 env. mine pg_ext.so was already in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/. I had to edit /usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb and manually specify location of pg_ext:

```
 require '/usr/local/share/gems/gems/pg-0.15.1/ext/pg_ext.so'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to relate to the question.  If it does please make your explanation clearer.